# Python - How to change the input field value using Selenium for

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to change the input field value in a form input using Selenium and Python, but unable to do so.

[See time picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFZpm.png)

I want to be able to perform .sendKeys() for each one (Hour, Minutes, Seconds, AM/PM). My code is the following:

```
end_time_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/form/ol/li[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/input')
end_mins_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ldb\:filter\:list\:1 > div > div > div.mins > div.mi_tx > input')
end_seconds_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ldb:filter:list:1"]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/input')
end_meridian_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/form/ol/li[2]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/input')


time_input.send_keys("10")
end_mins_input.send_keys("30")
end_seconds_input.send_keys("30")
end_meridian_input.send_keys("AM")
```

However, this is not working.

I also tried changing the value from the main input --> input id="ldb:filter:list:1:timeInput"

```
> <div class="time_pick" style="display: inline-block;width: 140px">
<input id="ldb:filter:list:1:timeInput" class="axw-wdb-time ldb-input" name="ldb:filter:list:1:timeInput" 
value="5:24:25 PM" placeholder="12:00:00 AM" aria-label="Time input End DateTime" data-timepicki-tim="10" 
data-timepicki-mini="24" data-timepicki-sec="25" data-timepicki-meri="PM" style="opacity: 1;">
<div class="timepicker_wrap " style="display: none; top: 20px; left: 0px;"><div class="arrow_top">
</div>
<div class="time" id="time_column"><div class="prev action-next">
</div>
<div class="ti_tx"><input type="text" class="timepicki-input">
</div>
<div class="next action-prev">
</div>
</div>
<div class="mins">
<div class="prev action-next">
</div>
<div class="mi_tx">
<input type="text" class="timepicki-input">
</div>
<div class="next action-prev">
</div>
</div><div class="seconds">
<div class="prev action-next">
</div>
<div class="sec_tx">
<input type="text" class="timepicki-input">
</div>
<div class="next action-prev">
</div>
</div>
<div class="meridian" id="meridian_column">
<div class="prev action-next">
</div>
<div class="mer_tx">
<input type="text" class="timepicki-input" readonly="">
</div>
<div class="next action-prev">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Those xPath's are very brittle, try to avoid just blindly copy/paste XPath from Chrome. It tends to give you brittle results like this.  Especially if you copy "full XPath". It is best to learn this stuff on your own, you'll be able to construct much more robust and reliable xPath and CSS selectors

Answer (score 0):

Is this indeed a webased application? or application based?

With web based, does the element expose another dropdown or typeahead container with different xpath?

If application, elements should be made discoverable in code...

Comment: It is a web based applicadtion. When you click the input it displays the time picker that you see in the image. The weird thing is that I can do a .send_keys for the Start date time and it's working just fine. However, it does not work for End date time until one point, because it sets the hour, but not minutes, and seconds.